# Іs there any relationship between $v(y)$ and $u(y)$ where $f(iy) = u(y) + iv(y)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let $f(z)$ be a differentiable function of the complex variable $z$ and let $f(iy) = u(y) + iv(y)$ for $z = iy$ where $y$ is a real variable.

**Question.** Is there any  relationship between the real and imaginary parts, $v(y)$ and $u(y)$?

For example, $f(z)$ is unknown, and we are given the explicit expression for $u(y)$, is it possible to find $v(y)$?

I was hoping that there might be some analogue to the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but so far I have not been able to find it.

Comment: Are you asking for a complex function satisfying $f(iy)=u(y)+iv(y)$ or a function from $i\mathbb{R}$ to complex numbers?

Comment: here $f$ is the same as it was in Cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: No $f$ is NOT the same as in the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If it were the same, then it would need to be defined for $x + iy$, not just $iy$. Also, the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are equivalent to the complex derivative. What derivative are you wanting your conditions to be equivalent to? The complex derivatve requires $f$ to be defined in two dimensions, not just one.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair. I agree, but my question was about something else - Let $f(t)$ be a function of a real variable $t$ and let $f(iy) = u(y) + iv(y)$. Is there a close relationship between the real and imaginary parts, $v(y)$ and $u(y)$? If there is, what is it?

Comment: Well, your question is different *now* that you've finally bothered to offer a little explanation, even if it is a bit weird, and offered only in a late comment, but still not in your post. What is weird about it is that if $f$ is defined on the real numbers, then the only way to take $f(iy)$ is for $y$ to be an imaginary number, so $u$ and $v$ must be defined on the imaginary numbers. Usually when dealing with complex numbers, we use $x$ and $y$ to represent real numbers, as you did at the start, and use $z$ and $w$ as non-real numbers. Still waiting for you to specify the derivative.

Comment: OK, let's continue to clarify the condition, the current version of which now looks like this: "Let $f(z)$ be a differentiable function of the complex variable $z$ and let for $z = iy$ where $y$ is a real variable, we have $f(iy) = u(y) + iv(y)$ . Is there a close relationship between the real and imaginary parts, $v(y)$ and $u(y)$? If there is, what is it?"

Comment: If you had some extra information, e.g. that $f$ was analytic in the right half plane and went to zero in the far field, you could relate them using something akin to the Hilbert transform.

Comment: Maybe this could help: [Kramers–Kronig relations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer: No.**

For example, let $f_1(z)=z+1$, and $f_2(z)=z^3+1$, both of them are analytic. We get

$$f_1(it)=1+i\cdot t,~~~~f_2(it)=1-i\cdot t^3$$

Both $f_1(it)$ and $f_2(it)$ have the same real part $u(t)=1$, but their imaginary part $v(t)$ are different. Hence, if only given the real function $u(t)$, there is **no way** to uniquely determine the real function $v(t)$.

---

**Remarks:**

Let $f(it)=u(t)+i\cdot v(t)$, after taking conjugate on both sides, we get $f(-it)=u(t)-i\cdot v(t)$. Take the addition and subtraction, we get

$$u(t)=\frac{f(it)+f(-it)}2,~~~~v(t)=\frac{f(it)-f(-it)}{2i}$$

We can see

$u(t)=u(-t)$, implies $u(t)$ is even function,

$v(-t)=-v(t)$, implies $v(t)$ is odd function.

Comment: Why would $f(-it) = u(t) - iv(t)$ ? If $f(z) = i(z + 1)$, this relation is not verified and $f(iy) = -y + i$ so $v = 1$ is not odd and $u(y) = -y$ is not even.

Comment: If you have read the comments under the OP, function $f$ is assuming to be a real function. @Cactus

Comment: No, $f$ is just analytic and a complex analytic function can't be real unless it is constant. Moreover, if $f$ is real on $i\mathbb{R}$, we have $v = 0$. The only case where we have $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$ is when $f$ develops as $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} a_nz^n$ in a neighborhood of $0$ (on any real number) and the $a_n$ are real (which is a very specific case).

Comment: The $f$ that OP assumes is different from what you interpreted. If you read the early comments under the OP, it assumes $f(x)$ is real valued function, $x\in \mathbb R$, then replace $x$ with $z$, where $z\in \mathbb C$ @Cactus

Comment: I might be blind but I see nowhere that $f$ has to be real valued on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3):

Even if $f$ is holomorphic, $u$ and $v$ can be any real analytic functions (and they are always real analytic because $f$ is), independant one from the other. Indeed, if $u$ and $v$ are real analytic on some open interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, take some $a \in I$ and write $u(y) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \alpha_n(y - a)^n$ and $v(y) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \beta_n(y - a)^n$ in some interval $]a - r,a + r[$. $u$ and $v$ are real thus each $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ are real.

Therefore, you can set $f_a(z) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} (\alpha_n + i\beta_n)(-iz - a)^n$, which is well defined on $U_a = -iB(a,r)$. We have $f_a(iy) = u(y) + iv(y)$ when $y \in \mathbb{R} \cap iU_a = ]a - r,a + r[$. If $U_a \cap U_b \neq \emptyset$, we have $f_a(iy) = f_b(iy) = u(y) + iv(y)$ when $y \in -iU_a \cap -iU_b \cap \mathbb{R}$, which is open and non-empty in $\mathbb{R}$ (so it admits accumulation points). By uniqueness of the analytic continuation, $f_a = f_b$ on $U_a \cap U_b$.

Therefore, the $(f_a)$ stick together to make a unique holomorphic function $f$ well defined on $U = \bigcup_{a \in I} U_a$, which is an open neighborhood of $-iI$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ verifies $f(iy) = u(y) + iv(y)$ when $y \in I$. It proves that such a $f$ always exist under the only condition that $u$ and $v$ both are real analytic.